# Xamarin forms-Custom AD login page

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible to remove the Microsoft login, create new user and all from the azure AD login page in xamarin forms.i refer to this link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding

but my xamarin login is going to the default Microsoft login page in xamarin.

Comment: Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: I created a Task<AuthenticationResult> Authenticate(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri); and called this in Android project.